# Multiple requests to Redis at once

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4, redis

Using Laravel 4.2 for reference. We have a products listing page, where we list up to 50 products on that page. We store the product ids, and then loop through the IDs and request the Product object in Redis (through the Cache object). If there's 50 objects, there's 50 calls going back and forth between the web server and Redis. Is there anyway to pull all 50 at once  (without caching all 50 objects at once?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Redis pipelining](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/redis#pipelining).

```
Redis::pipeline(function($pipe)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
    {
        $pipe->set("key:$i", $i);
    }
});
```

It'll return an array of responses in the same order the commands were executed in.